# Android: Finding Memory Leaks with MAT

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I am having major issues with my app.  When I run it, and choose a certain activity, the screen goes black and it basically freezes.  I get a whole long list of GC messages in logcat.  I downloaded the MAT and had it analyze a heap to find the memory leaks.  My problem is that I am new at this, and I have no idea where it is telling me the leaks are.

Below are the three it gives me.  Can anyone explain to me how to figure these out?  I have been googling like crazy and cannot seem to find any help.

Problem 1:

```
The class "android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$ActiveDatabases", loaded by "<system class loader>", occupies 652,048 (20.70%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of "java.util.HashMap$HashMapEntry[]" loaded by "<system class loader>".
```

Problem 2:

```
6,831 instances of "java.lang.String", loaded by "<system class loader>" occupy 456,472 (14.49%) bytes.
```

Problem 3:

```
127 instances of "org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.X509CertificateObject", loaded by "<system class loader>" occupy 451,280 (14.32%) bytes. These instances are referenced from one instance of "java.util.Hashtable$HashtableEntry[]", loaded by "<system class loader>"
```

Comment: [Here's a Google IO talk on using MAT](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk)

Comment: I actually already watched this, but thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should check SQLiteDatabase cursor if closed when not be used,especially after meet exception.
I think you should observe these problems you ‘believe’ for a long time。Because MAT only conjecture these.U must have evidence that some object occupy a large memory to cause your app  killed by system。Otherwise，u should ‘search’ android famous memory leak problems with google to get a clue。

good luck！

Comment: This actually helped.  I don't think I was closing my cursors correctly.  To fix this, I created a separate method in my DB Helper Class to close the cursor if it was open, and called that before calling to close the database.  Thank you!